# Combining 5 ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 5 differents ggplots that I would like to combine.
I am using this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
SPC6h_lm<- lm(SPC6h ~ APO, 
                     data = data)
RSQ <- summary(SPC6h_lm)$r.squared
a <- unname(coef(SPC6h_lm)[1])
b <- unname(coef(SPC6h_lm)[2])
ggplot(data, aes(x=APO, y=SPC6h)) + 
  geom_point(size=3, colour="#56B4E9") +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", col="#56B4E9", se=FALSE)
```

Basically my y-axis should remain the same ("SPC6H") as I need to compare it to every other column of my dataframe (here it is the column "APO" which is my x-axis). I would like to have multiple regressions instead of multiple plots.
I would also like to have the equations displaying on the lines instead of the title.

[image]

Comment: So do you want one plot or 5? If one, should it have one common y axis but five overlaid different x axes and five regression lines?

Comment: Actually I just realize my two axis should remain the same. But I need 5 regressions :)

Comment: I tried to use examples like this one http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/ but it doesn't match my data: my first column lists the individuals (data=read.table("File.txt", sep="\t", header=T, dec=".")
rownames(data) = data[,1] ) My 2nd column is the y-axis and the 5 other columns are different series with different values of the same parameter (x-axis)

Comment: @Janet You might want to reshape your data to "long" format before plotting, so the 5 columns/series become one column, and then add a new column to indicate which of the 5 the data belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple regression elements (e.g., eq.label, R2 and P) to one plot, you can use `ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq()`. Also, you can change the digits if needed. `all_groups` will have your y variable names and `values` their actual value.

```
# Change the df format 
df_long=lattice::environmental%>% # a dataset that match your current structure
  dplyr::mutate(x=as.numeric(row.names(.)))%>% #my x variable
  tidyr::gather(key = "all_groups",value="values",1:4) # turn my columns 1,2,3,4 into rows 


ggplot(df_long,aes(x=x,y=values,color=all_groups))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=T)+
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(stat(eq.label),stat(rr.label),stat(p.value.label), sep = "~~~")), 
                        formula = "y~x", parse = TRUE,p.digits = 2)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.6)))+ #extra space at the top of the y axis 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you, could you confirm that I should substitute "lattice::environmental%>%" for my data set? Also what does the dot between bracket means and what should I replace it with in this expression: "(row.names(.)))%>%" What do the "%>%" mean?

Comment: yes @Janet, `lattice::environmental` for your data. `(.)` means something like use the data before the `%>%` to do something else. In this case, it will use the "row names" from `lattice::environmental` and create "mutate" a new variable `x`.... you should have it so you can do `tidyr::gather(your_data_set, key = "all_groups", value=" values",1:4) ` if you are not familiar with `pipes (%>%)`. Pipes allow you to string together commands to get a flow of results [more info here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/)